# Cluster nodes only used by internal pods

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We are using GKE to host our apps with Anthos, our default node pool ils set to autoscale but I noticed that out of 5 running pods, only 2 are hosting our actual services.

All the others are running internal services like this:

[image: only internal services]

The issue with that is that there's not enough room for running our own services. I guess these are vital for the cluster otherwise the cluster would autoscale and the nodes would get removed.

What would be the best approach to solve this issue? I thought of upgrading the nodes machine type to allow more resources per node and have more room within them and thus have less running nodes, but I wanted to make sure I was not simply missing something on how GKE works.

I've been now digging for quite some time but it seems that would be my only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GKE itself requires several add-on resources which are deployed as part of your cluster.  You can fine tune the [resource usage of some of the GKE add-ons](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/small-cluster-tuning) for smaller clusters.  Additionally, Anthos each Anthos capability you enable typically deploys a set of controllers as well.  GKE and Anthos try to minimize the compute resources used by these services / controllers, but you do need to account for them when calculating the right size(s) for your nodes.  A good rule of thumb is to assume that system services/controllers will use ~1 vCPU when using GKE/Anthos (it's typically lower than that, but it makes things easier).  So if your workloads all request >=1 vCPU, you'll likely need to use nodes that have a minimum of 4 vCPUs. You'll also want to enable the cluster autoscaler for your node pools if you don't want to pre-provision everything.

A better option would be to use [node auto-provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning) as in this case you don't need to create/manage your own node pools as GKE will automatically add/remove nodes / node pools based on the resources requested by your deployments.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Autoscaling is indeed enabled but it's popping a new node when deploying a new version of a service due to the low limit of 2cpu per nodes. As you described it'd make more sense to switch to a higher tier of nodes with a 4vCPUs cap or maybe benchmark the requirements of our stack a bit better